# tables and links messing the code up

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with PHP and links, I mean, I'm trying to use `<a href` to link the id of a ticket and then display it to user, but the problem is that the link I get is like

http://localhost/ucp/viewticket.php?ticketid=8%3Etest%3C/a%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3EUpute%20i%20informacije%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E2016-08-26%2000:06:59%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E9%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3ESale_Lesa%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Ca%20href=

and it should only be like

http://localhost/ucp/viewticket.php?ticketid=8

This is the code:

```
if ($result = $con->query($query)) 
{
    echo '
    <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
       <th>ID Tiketa</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Kategorija</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
    ';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Autor'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"viewticket.php?ticketid=". $row['ID'] .">". $row['Naslov'] ."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Kategorija'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Datum'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your Markup everything should be fine:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Autor'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="viewticket.php?ticketid='. $row['ID'] .'">'. $row['Naslov'] .'</a></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Kategorija'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Datum'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

The Reason for this is, that there is a big difference between Single Quotes and Double Quotes.

Single Quotes are not parsed by PHP, so

```
$variable = 'hello';
echo '$variable'
```

will still return: $variable

While

```
echo "$variable"
```

will parse the string to: Hello

This way you would have seen, that you missed an escaped double quote.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a double quote at the end of the href link so it's including all the HTML that follows as the link too. I've fixed it below by add \" before the end of the "a" tag.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"viewticket.php?ticketid=". $row['ID'] ."\">". $row['Naslov'] ."</a></td>";
```